# Generate single-file HTML code documentation

Tags: html, pdf, documentation, doxygen

How can I use Doxygen to create the HTML documentation as a single, very long file? I want something like the RTF output, but as HTML.

The reason: I need my API published as a single, printable, document. Something that can be loaded into Word, converted to PDF, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [HTMLDOC](https://www.msweet.org/htmldoc/index.html) to convert the generated html files to a single html file. (I did not try it myself)

The [manual](https://www.msweet.org/htmldoc/htmldoc.html) includes the following example to generate a html from two source html files:

```
htmldoc --book -f output.html file1.html file2.html
```

But there is also a gui.

Comment: it doesn't embed css and other stuff

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an option that will produce the output as a single HTML file, but the RTF output may be suitable if you need an editable output format (I haven't tried this myself so I don't know how well this works).

If you want good quality printable output, then Doxygen can output LaTeX format (set `GENERATE_LATEX` to `YES` in your doxygen configuration file). This can then be converted to PDF, although you'll need to install a LaTeX distribution such as [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was missing something. PDF is ok, but I wanted an editable format.

Comment: LaTeX is editable, but you would need to learn the markup language. I don't know if this would be too high a barrier for you.